# Select count of rows in another table in a Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I don't know quite how to phrase this in Laravel query-builder so please help me .

```
SELECT A.*, 
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM B WHERE B.a_id = A.id) AS TOT,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C WHERE C.a_id = A.id) AS KOK
FROM A
```

Comment: First off what have you tried yourself and is your query correct? It seems a little ackward.

Comment: You can always use `DB::select(DB::raw($queryString));`

Comment: pls, give me an example.